# Are Vita TV and PlayStation TV compatible?

Tags: playstation-tv, ps-vita-tv

I have a Vita TV but have moved to a region where it is called PlayStation TV. Previously you could only use Asia PSN accounts with Vita TV.

Now that it has launched globally, are the devices now account region free?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact the PlayStation TV is basically the PSVITA Chipset in a SetTopBox, with very little software customization. So, just like PSV, it is region free. To run all PS Vita games, you'll need to configure HiddenApplications though, but I'm not sure if I can explain this on this site.